# Running multiple applications with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I have my directory structure set up as such.

```
src/main/scala/main/Main.scala
src/main/scala/scripts/MainScript.scala
```

The script is a background job that will be running.

I've used `sbt-assembly` before to package up the main file into a jar to be deployed but I'm not sure how to create the two separate jars with `sbt-assembly` or `sbt-native-packager`. How would I go about doing that and what would be the best approach for this problem?

I would be looking to do something similar to this.

```
java -jar main.jar $PORT
java -jar scriptMain.jar
```

Comment: Sbt native packager creates deployable artifacts for you. You can use Sbt assembly and Sbt native packager in tandem. We create rpm packages for spark where the fat jar created by Sbt assembly gets used.

Comment: @Manas Is it possible to code up a solution with `sbt-assembly` inside of `build.sbt` to create two separate JARs at the same time? I've used it before to create a single JAR. Because once I have those, I can create another file to do what's happening in the above code block.

Comment: @Manas Should I be creating a multi-project build? So I would have the common code in `common`, MainScript in `script`, and Main in `main`. And build the JARs that way?

Comment: Not sure how multi-project build will help you. I would still go with a `sbt-assembly` and use two scripts. One to call `main` and another to call `script`.  Basically you will end up having same jar copied to two packages.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this only with native-packager would be the following.

- Put all your main classes in `src/main/scala`
- Define a `mainClass in Compile := Some("foo.bar.Main")` that should run as default
- [add additional scripts](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formats/universal.html#getting-started-with-universal-packaging) in `src/universal/bin` that you would like to provide. These scripts can call the main script generated by native-packager [and set the](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.org/en/latest/archetypes/java_app/index.html#start-script-options) `-main` parameter to the class you want to call.

Now you have an output package (e.g. a zip, rpm, deb) that has the following structure. Assuming your app is called **myApp** and you provided to other bin scripts called **otherApp1** / **otherApp2**

```
lib/ (jars live here)
conf/ (configuration files here, if any)
bin/
  myApp
  otherApp1
  otherApp2
```

Unfortunately I have no example for the script (my bash-foo isn't good enough for instant magic on SO). In the end the scripts (otherApp1,otherApp2) should just pass the parameters they receive to the native-packager script (myApp).

There is [an issue #633](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/633) that provides an automated way to generate scripts like this.

hope that helps,
Muki